# @Profile Spring Annotation in Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-annotations

I have a Spring Boot + Apache Camel project that works brilliantly. I just added a new bean though where I wanted to have its implementation be profile-specific. I created Spring tests to verify it, and it works as expected, but when I run the server I get the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: MyFancyBean
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.RegistryBean.getBean(RegistryBean.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.model.language.MethodCallExpression.createExpression(MethodCallExpression.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.model.language.MethodCallExpression.createPredicate(MethodCallExpression.java:210)
    at org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.createPredicate(ExpressionDefinition.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ValidateDefinition.createProcessor(ValidateDefinition.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ValidateDefinition.createProcessor(ValidateDefinition.java:35)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:545)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:506)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:222)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1068)
```

I have an interface and two implementations:

```
public interface MyFancyBean { ... }

public class FooFancyBean implements MyFancyBean { ... }

public class NonFooFancyBean implements MyFancyBean { ... }
```

Depending on profile, the correct bean is read instantiated:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    @Profile("foo")
    MyFancyBean fooBean() {
        return new FooFancyBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("!foo")
    MyFancyBean nonFooBean() {
        return new NonFooFancyBean();
    }
}
```

I've verified this works a couple of ways. First, a couple tests:

```
@ActiveProfiles("anything-but-foo")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example", "com.jtv.spring.boot"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Component
public class NonFooBean_SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyFancyBean bean;

    @Test
    // ... here "bean" is instantiated as "NonFooFancyBean"
```

So the test works.

Further, when I start my app, depending on profile the correct bean in my @Configuration class above is called.

But **Camel** is still angry and says "NoSuchBeanException" on startup.

FWIW, here's how I'm referencing the bean:

```
@Component
public class MyCamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // [...]
        from("direct:processStuff").
        validate().method("MyFancyBean").
        process("MyProcessor");
    }


}
```

How do I get Camel to honor this config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoooo... Y'all get to be my [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) today. I just autowired it. (This doesn't work for my processor, which is why it didn't occur to me initially.)

```
@Component
public class MyCamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // [...]
        @Autowired MyFancyBean myFancyBean;

        from("direct:processStuff").
        validate().method(myFancyBean).
        process("MyProcessor");
    }
}
```

Comment: (Not allowed to answer my own question for two days... what's that about?)

Comment: Hehe .. rubber ducky.